# Rx.min.js file is not present in the "node_modules\rxjs\bundles\" after npm install rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to use the component RxJS to my project. I have performed `npm install rxjs`, but there is no Rx.min.js in the node_modeles/bundles file. Instead, there are rxjs.umd.js and rxjs.umd.min.js.

Please tell me, why Rx.min.js is not installed?

Comment: you should use libraries installed via npm using `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` or `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: If you have generated the Angular project using Angular CLI you would not need to install `rxjs` explicitly as CLI would add and install it for you. Also, it would be great if you could provide your Angular version and node.js version

Comment: Do have a look at this https://angular.io/guide/rx-library and https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages

Comment: Are you using Angular? If yes, could you tell me what do you need the Rx.min.js for?

Answer (score 1):

It is installed but you have to import it in your project as a module.

In your js file:

`import * as Rx from "rxjs"`

should do the trick!

Then you can use methods starting from `Rx`

Example:

```
const mySubject = new Rx.Subject();

mySubject.subscribe((n) => {
  console.info("NEW VALUE", n);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  mySubject.next("FOO");
}, 1000);
```

You can also import single components with

`import {Subject} from "rxjs";`

or

`import {finalize} from "rxjs/operators";`

Comment: Your first approach is not recommended as  Tree Shaker won't be able to detect which operators are in use. As a result, all operators (and static methods of Observable) will be included in the build. Which would result in a significant increase in the generated artifacts.

Comment: The Tree Shaking is related to Angular Cli. I think that since she's looking for the minified javascript file, he's not using Angular.

Comment: See Tags in question, It includes Angular

Comment: I would not jump to the conclusion, May be out of curiosity or unawareness of the angular eco system it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you executed `npm install rxjs`

Ensure your package.json has rxjs. Else execute the command `npm install rxjs --save`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

install it using this command: `npm i rx`

Then you can find it in the following folder:

```
node_modules/rx/dist/rx.min.js
```